# Yii::app() method is undefined

Tags: javascript, php, css, model-view-controller, yii

I was trying to include a CSS file into a view such as follows:

```
$baseUrl = Yii::app()->baseUrl; 
$cs = Yii::app()->getClientScript();
$cs->registerScriptFile($baseUrl.'/js/weather.js');
$cs->registerCssFile($baseUrl.'/css/weatherstyles.css');
```

But I receive a message that says that Yii::app() is undefined. Why does this happens? Do I need to include something else in the view so the method will be defined?

I'm using yii 2.0.7 by the way. Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1):

But in your code you use Yii 1.* version syntax

in Yii 2.* you should use `Yii::$app`